# Dynamically pass the type name to a static_cast

Tags: c++

Is it possible to dynamically choose the type you wish to cast to, during runtime?

For example, suppose I have:

`ClassType * pointer=static_cast<ClassType*>(baseClassPointer);`

At run time, however, I'd like to choose what the `ClassType` is, rather than having to hardcode it into the function.

Is this possible? The two ways I'm thinking I'd want to use it is either passing an actual `char *` that contains the name of the type I want to use, or somehow extracting the type information from an existing class and using that as the cast.

The reason I want to do this, is I have several derived classes from a common base class. I can get the basic functionality of the base class for each of the derived classes, but if I want a pointer to access some of the specific functionality that only exists in the derived class, I need to cast that pointer as such. And I'd like to have a function that allows me to do this casting dynamically for any of the derived classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates might be able to serve your purpose here for whenever you need it to statically cast upwards.

```
template <typename TTo> derived_cast ( BaseClass* b ) { 
     static_assert( std::is_base_of<BaseClass, TTo>::value, "You can't cast to a class that's not derived from BaseClass!" );
     return static_cast<TTo*>( b );
}
```

The syntax becomes a bit more compressed then:

```
 Derived* d = derived_cast<Derived>( b );
```

The static_assert to makes sure `TTo` is actually derived and such.

Now, for run-time, you'd have to use `dynamic_cast`, but that involves other things than what the code you have up there implies.

***EDIT:*** Beyond this point are dragons of a crazy kind.

In C++, dynamically casting and operating on an object (without ever knowing that type at compile-time) is impossible, save for using a robust base class *or* `if/else` on some kind of run-time identifier to *then* provide static type information. In almost all cases, you would be better to just use a `virtual` method on a base class and then override them in derived classes. Switching on strings and other things is not only slow but painful when you have to keep adding extra cases: do not do it. However, if you are going to ignore my advice, here's some built-in pieces you can work with to get sort of what you want:

`typeid` - an operator that defines an implementation-defined, but unique-to-the-class, object (`type_info`) that compares uniquely to that class. You can compare them `typeid( Dog) == typeid( Dog )` and get true/false correctly. This will allow you some run-time typing information.

`dynamic_cast` - a cast that fails on up-casting or to a class of a certain type (abridged definition, for more information see [cppreference on `dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)). You can use this to dynamically cast pointers and other such things, with it returning `null` on failure to cast. It might help you here, but you still need to know the types statically that you're working with (after switching on, say, typeid).

With these two, you could do a better implementation of what you see in the other answer with the `string` usage. But that's about it. Anything else requires things like `boost::variant`, a stronger base class, or a different design. A stronger base class sounds like what you could use here, but I can't say with 100% certainty.

Good luck!

Comment: I like the elegant syntax! That's a good example of a template at work. It would be cool if I could pass a string into the function, and that string is used as the class type assertion, rather than me needing to know in the code what the `Derived` is.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns Unfortunately (and I mean, _REALLY_ unfortunately), it's not quite that simple in C++. C++ is a very statically-typed language. You can't go creating or random-type-casting at runtime. You will have to know beforehand what "type" you want. The closest you can get is by enabling RTTI in your compiler and using `type_index`, but even in any casting function you'd have to know what end-type you want, otherwise you'd need to use a more robust base class.

Comment: I think in your code snippet the reference to `baseClassPointer` in the return statement should just be `b`

Answer (score 1):

Bad design spotted !
What about overriding your derived classes ? You are messing with something really dangerous

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by "override" -- you mean subclass the subclassed clas?

Comment: Oops sorry I meant overriding some base methods (via virtual). Looking for the derived type at runtime is really bugging me. You could try the RTTI way (not portable) or adding a method in your derived classes to make them "self-identifying". Something like char* getType().

Answer (score 1):

If you have for example base class Animal, and you have derived classes Dog and Cat, you can always cast Animal to Dog or Cat (if you know which it is):

```
void doCustomOperation(Animal *animal, string runtimeDecision) {
    if (runtimeDecision == "dog") {
        ((Dog *)animal).bark();
    }
    if (runtimeDecision == "cat") {
        ((Cat *)animal).chaseMouse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worthy point. Maybe gets me halfway to what I want but could be acceptable.

Comment: Could you please explain why is this not useful enough? I am not sure I fully grasped what you need.

Comment: It still requires that I hard code the name of the desired class into the function. Suppose in your example I pass a string, but rather than test that string and then cast based on it, I simply use the string as the name of the type; alternately, suppose I have a way to simply extract the class type from the object, then use that as the cast, which I think you can do in Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could do this at runtime (which I don't think you can), what would you do with the derived class pointer you get back?  You wouldn't know at the time you write the code what type of object you'll get back so how would you know what methods you can call?

I think you would be better off either adding virtual methods to your base class to capture the necessary functionality or alternatively you could employ the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).